# Can I sell my business idea in exchange for a job at the company that might be interested in it?

Tags: payment-terms

Me and my brother have an idea of the brand new product that would solve one widespread problem among the smartphone users. But due to the fact that we don’t have required resources and opportunities to make that idea come to life, I’ve contacted the company that might be interested in my idea and would be able to realize that project. I described them the problem and explained how my product would be able to solve it and have provided its advantages over devices that perform the same function. The COO of the company has replied me and wants to discuss that idea together and ensured me that it would be under NDA. Since I don’t have any prototype of my device but only the pictures of its appearance and full explanation of the mechanism, what can I ask in exchange of my idea to them? I don’t have experience in such things. As a graduate I want to offer them my idea in exchange for a chance for me and my brother to work for their company and some percentage from the sales in case they decide to produce it. Does it sound possible? Should I include my conditions in the NDA? And what type of NDA should I use then? I don’t know what steps should I make now? I can’t afford attorney to help me with my occasion, but I hope that I will be able to get advice from you guys.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Once you tell them all they need to know, what do you have? what prevents them to patent it if you were not wise enough to do it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it has absolutely nothing to do with freelancing.

Comment: @SOIA: rephrase the title as "Can I sell my business idea in exchange for a freelancer job at the company that might be interested in it?"

Comment: Meh.. I still think it's far more about venture sales and and protecting IP than it is about freelancing. Just my opinion though.

Comment: Even re-phrasing the question, this is likely a better fit on law or startups than here, as it's mostly a legal question.

Answer (score 1):

Beware that you cannot claim ownership of a mere idea. Intellectual property can be protected when sufficient effort has been developed around it. Make sure to clearly state in writing what specific concepts/ideas you think you are bringing and are subjected to the NDA (but obviously you deliver them *after* the NDA has been signed).

Be conscious that with no resources you have about no chance of protecting your findings, other than by relying on trust.

If your baby seduces this COO, then it makes sense to set a price, which may include hiring you. The NDA isn't the place for such a negotiation. You'll do that later in the frame of a contractual commercial agreement.

Last piece of advice: whatever it is, don't believe that you found the idea of the century.